# how to call the kernel module from a user space Terminal into an application

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-3#chp-2-ITERM-4135 this link describes the user space and kernel space communication. 
could anyone explain it with a simple user space application program in c that links & communicates(send / receives values) to the kernel object.?

Answer (score 0):

The program `insmod`, available on most Linux machines (but requiring sudo privileges to run) instructs the kernel to load a specified module (kernel object) through the *system call* `init_module`.

More generally, user-space programs communicate with the kernel through these system calls, which are essentially requests to the kernel from user space. Any application you write in C must use system calls in some way to interact with the system (for example, `printf` uses the `write` system call under the hood to put characters on the screen).

Answer (score 0):

Just open a file with `open(2)`. The compiler will add code to the application for this call which will put the function arguments on the stack and make it crash in a certain way (see [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)). The kernel catches all the crashes and handles them.

Since this is a "good" crash, the kernel will look up which function to invoke, get the arguments from the stack and invoke the function.

The reason for this complicated approach is security: By "crashing", the application completely relinquishes control. The CPU will switch to a different mode, too. In this mode, it can access the hardware (in "application" mode, any access to the hardware leads to an "illegal access" crash which terminates your app).

The `open(2)` function itself can't do much. Instead, it will check which file system can handle the request and invoke the open function of the file system. File systems are implemented as kernel modules.